# Unit Test Method that uses Linq EF 6

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using EF 6 and MVC 5.  I have a method callded MaxScore, see below.  I've tested it and it works within my project.  I'm new to unit testing so I decided to try it out against this method.  When I debug the test I get an error, "Object reference not set to instance of an object".  The error points to line 6 in the method below.  Any ideas?

Here is my method:

```
private HandicapSystemContext db = new HandicapSystemContext();

public int MaxScore(double handicap)
    {
        int _maxScore = 0;
        _maxScore = db.AdjustedGrossScores.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MinimiumHandicap <= handicap && x.MaximumHandicap >= handicap).Score;
        return _maxScore;
    }
```

Here is my unit test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMaxScore()
{
    int _maxScore = 0;
    Calculation hc = new Calculation();
    _maxScore = hc.MaxScore(10);
    Assert.AreEqual(_maxScore, 7);
}
```

Comment: Google is your friend.. take a look at for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, I had to add Entity Framewwork (Using NuGet) to the Test Project.  I added a connectionstring to the app.config file.  Since I'm using Code First and dropping and regenerating the database on model changes, I had to copy the localDB files to the /bin/Debug/ folder.  I will have to recopy the database every time the database changes until I get to a solid state and switch over to a Sql Server database.